# How to append the category field data nested inside a section to an input tag?

Tags: craft3, templating, categories, frontend, nested

1. while clicking the input tag it should display its related entries
2. Based on the category field the data selected in the backend value should get appended to the input tag.
3. When looping through the section the category field data should be displayed in the front end

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case, i.e. describe in more detail what you're trying to achieve? What's an "input tag"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.